# Get Azure Password Reset Authentication Phone attribute using microsoft graph library

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

How can we query Azure Directory and get the Authentication Phone number used for password reset. It is not the mobile number that is exposed using Microsoft graph Library. We are using MVC 5, C# VS2017.
Thank you, Tim:

Currently, we use the below code to get user properties however, the phone number used during a password reset is not there.

```cs
// Get the current user's profile.
public async Task<List<ResultsItem>> GetMe(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
{
    List<ResultsItem> items = new List<ResultsItem>();

    // Get the current user's profile.
    User me = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();

    if (me != null)
    {

        // Get user properties.
        items.Add(new ResultsItem
        {
            Display = me.DisplayName,
            Id = me.Id,
            Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { Resource.Prop_Upn, me.UserPrincipalName },
                { Resource.Prop_Id, me.Id }
            }
        });
    }
    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately you currently cannot use Microsoft Graph to programmatically set the strong authentication properties, which is used for Self Service Password Reset and for Multi-Factor Authentication.

This is a frequently requested features, it is on our backlog and I hope to deliver it soon, however I cannot provide a specific timeline when it will be available.

Comment: This contradicts sharing technology which enhances overall security - its our users that we are sharing the information with yet we can't get access to this information? Very poor judgement for Microsoft strategist. Vr, Tim: